# Which microversion of Python 2.7 introduced set comprehension?

Tags: python, python-2.7, version, language-features, set-comprehension

It works in my interpreter (2.7.12).

From http://sopython.com/wiki/In_which_Python_version_was_feature_X_introduced%3F I know, that it was introduced in 2.7.

Unfortunately the online documentation is available only for 2.7.13, so I can not check in which microversion was the feature introduced.

Comment: New function are always added in a major (2) or minor release (2.7) not in a patch (2.7.13). There have been only very few exceptions.

Comment: http://bugs.python.org/issue2333 strongly implies it might have made it into the 2.7.0 release but I haven't been able to find more specific confirmation of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.7.html#python-3-1-features) suggests that all versions of Python 2.7 have set comprehensions as they were backported from Python 3.1.